# Difference between AにB and AはB

Tags: particles, particle-に

The context is this tweet:

> **セットリストに適当**！って書いてます。笑

I could understand more easily if は was used instead of に. How does に change the meaning?

Does an inference have to be made here to understand what is appropriate?

Comment: I think you are right, yibe -- you should add this explanation as an answer, not a comment, so folks can vote on it.

Answer (score 9):

I think this person (maybe a musician) just means:

> セットリストに「適当！」って書いてます。笑
>
> I just write 「適当！」("play without a plan!") on a [set list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_list). lol

Comment: Since there is no negative within the quotations in the original Japanese, I think a slightly more accurate translation would be "I just write 「"whatever!」 on a set list. lol"

Answer (score 2):

`に` means that the action is being directed at the subject in question. `は` means... well, `は` is defined as a "topic marker", but trying to really define its usage is a whole topic of its own.

Anyway, `適当【てきとう】` in this context means "flippant", and so the speaker is being flippant *toward* the set list. In English I think the more natural way to say it would be that the speaker is being flippant *about* the set list.

`セットリストは適当` , in this situation, would mean that the set list itself is flippant somehow, but it would be vague about why, who made it that way, and how exactly.